# What does "bin" in "Ich bin vor 2 Jahren nach Berlin gezogen" mean?

Tags: grammar-identification

I translated "I moved to Berlin 2 years ago" to German, using Google translate, and it says "Ich bin vor 2 Jahren nach Berlin gezogen".

I'm trying to figure out the logic behind the "bin". The first thing that came to my mind was that it would be the present perfect, translating literally to "I have, two years ago, to Berlin, moved". However, apparently, the present perfect in German would be "ich habe".

What is the logic behind this "bin"?

Comment: http://canoonet.eu/inflection/ziehen:V:haben:sein https://www.dwds.de/wb/ziehen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

German *Perfekt* is built with the *haben* auxiliary for **most** verbs. However, there is a significant minority of verbs which build their *Perfekt* with the *sein* auxiliary. Some other verbs build their *Zustandspassiv* voice with the *sein* auxiliary instead.

*Ziehen* is an extra special case, as it allows all three options.

> Ich habe eine Niete gezogen. *(Perfekt, 1st meaning)*

*I drew a blank.*

> Ich bin zu ihm gezogen. *(Perfekt, 2nd meaning)*

*I moved to him.*

> Dieses Blech ist gezogen. *(Zustandspassiv **or** predicative expression, 1st meaning)*

*This metal sheet is drawn.*

Comment: Very clear. Thank you very much

Comment: Isn't it that all verbs that describe or imply movement are formed with sein and the others with haben? (All implies the great majority, exceptions may occur)

Comment: Verbs that imply movement to the great majority build their *Perfekt* with *sein*. However, the opposite isn't true. There are many more verbs which build their *Perfekt* with *sein*. A lot of those belong to the same group as *ziehen* with two separate meanings depending on if *sein* or *haben* is used. And the *Zustandspassiv* also plays into that. E.g. consider *landen* and *verbrennen*.

Comment: Just as a personal theory, my impression is German follows Latin closely in this regard. The *Partizip II* has a both *Perfekt* and a *Passiv* meaning, and the auxiliary (*haben, sein, werden*, but also *bleiben*, *ansehen als*, *gelten als* etc.) used determines which of the two (or even both) matters most.